# Cant parse afnetworking json response to nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I am attempting to call an external API with the following afnetworking request code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        destination, @"destination",
                        nil];

[manager POST:baseUrl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        completion(nil, responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    completion(error, nil);
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

When I print out the responseObject I get the following which is the json that I expect to see:

[image]

However when I attempt to access the code e.g. responseObject[@"code"] I get some strange text:

```
(__NSCFNumber *) $0 = 0xb00000000000fa33 (long)4003
```

I then tried to parse this with NSStringwithformat %ld, but that returns:

```
 (__NSCFString *) $1 = 0x000060800005a850 @"-5764607523034170829"
```

Not sure what's going on here, whether the responseObject has even been parsed properly as an NSDictionary

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what is going on here, but I recommend to use Gloss framework for JSON Serializing/Deserializing to map JSON on objects directly.

http://harlankellaway.com/Gloss/

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what is happening but it's strange

so i suggest you can Debug it step by step

Answer (score 0):

What i suppose is that the number is a float, try

```
NSNumber *num = [responseObject objectForKey:@"code"];
int theValue = [num intValue];
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

so what you have to do is, inside you success block,

```
NSDictionary *result = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

for(NSDictionary *all in result){
   int code = [all objectForKey:@"code"];
}
```

hope this will help to your.

**note : better to use `model` and add those objects to a `mutable array`.**